Why is it that making a div 'display: flex' changes the height of the inner div?
I have the following HTML/CSS code, whenever I toggle the display: flex in .cards-container the height of the .card div seems to shrink (when display: flex is not present) and grow (when display: flex is present).
I was wondering what's the reason for this behaviour, I thought that flexbox didn't affect the size of inner divs.
When display: flex is present in .cards-container:


.cards-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.card {
  width: 250px;
  height: fit-content;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}

.card>.card-bottom-container {
  margin: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card>.card-bottom-container>.card-tags-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.card>.card-bottom-container>.card-tags-container>.card-tag {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
<div class="cards-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-bottom-container">
      <div class="card-tags-container">
        <a href="/path-1" class="card-tag"></a>
        <a href="/path-2" class="card-tag"></a>
        <a href="/path-3" class="card-tag"></a>
        <a href="/path-4" class="card-tag"></a>
        <a href="/path-5" class="card-tag"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



When display: flex is NOT present in .cards-container (note: that's the only thing that has changed, everything else remains the same):


.cards-container {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.card {
  width: 250px;
  height: fit-content;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}

.card>.card-bottom-container {
  margin: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card>.card-bottom-container>.card-tags-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.card>.card-bottom-container>.card-tags-container>.card-tag {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
<div class="cards-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-bottom-container">
      <div class="card-tags-container">
        <a href="/path-1" class="card-tag"></a>
        <a href="/path-2" class="card-tag"></a>
        <a href="/path-3" class="card-tag"></a>
        <a href="/path-4" class="card-tag"></a>
        <a href="/path-5" class="card-tag"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




The reason for the height difference is that in some scenarios the top and bottom margins on .card-bottom-container will collapse, and in other circumstances they will not. Here is a snippet to demonstrate some scenarios.


.cards-container {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.cards-container.with-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cards-container.with-border .card {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.card > .card-bottom-container {
  margin: 1em;
  gap: 1em;
}

.card > .card-bottom-container > .card-tags-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid magenta;
}

.card > .card-bottom-container > .card-tags-container > .card-tag {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.cards-container.with-padding-instead-of-margin .card {
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cards-container.with-padding-instead-of-margin .card > .card-bottom-container {
  margin: 0;
}

code {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
<p>First <strong>without</strong> <code>display: flex</code> on <code>.cards-container</code>. The top and bottom margins of <code>.card-bottom-container</code> extend outside <code>.card</code>, resulting in <code>.card</code> being only as high as the red dots. You can’t see these margins because they collapse with the margins of the neighbouring elements.</p>

<div class="cards-container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-bottom-container">
            <div class="card-tags-container">
                <a href="/path-1" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-2" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-3" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-4" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-5" class="card-tag"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Next <strong>with</strong> <code>display: flex</code> on <code>.cards-container</code>. The top and bottom margins of <code>.card-bottom-container</code> are now contained within <code>.card</code>.</p>

<div class="cards-container with-flex">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-bottom-container">
            <div class="card-tags-container">
                <a href="/path-1" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-2" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-3" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-4" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-5" class="card-tag"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Next with a border around <code>.card</code>. The top and bottom margins of <code>.card-bottom-container</code> are contained within <code>.card</code>.</p>

<div class="cards-container with-border">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-bottom-container">
            <div class="card-tags-container">
                <a href="/path-1" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-2" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-3" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-4" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-5" class="card-tag"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Finally without any margin around <code>.card-bottom-container</code>, and instead with padding inside <code>.card</code>. This is the most straight-forward layout, and thus the recommended one.</p>

<div class="cards-container with-padding-instead-of-margin">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-bottom-container">
            <div class="card-tags-container">
                <a href="/path-1" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-2" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-3" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-4" class="card-tag"></a>
                <a href="/path-5" class="card-tag"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



I suggest you review this material on collapsing margins to help you understand how margins behave. Then I suggest you change your code to use padding instead of margins, as per my last example.

It is a collapsing margin issue. But, to put is simply, margins do not collapse in flexbox.
